# Is there any other simple way to change my vanilla JavaScript code?

Tags: javascript, simplify

Is there a way I can make my code even more simple?

FYI, I'm a beginner and I've been learning JavaScript only for a week.

Thank you!

```
let array = [1,2,4,591,392,391,2,5,10,2,1,1,1,20,20];
// from above to [[1, 1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2], 4, 5, 10, [20, 20], 391, 392, 591]

const answer = (arr) => {
    arr.sort((a, b) => {
        return a - b;
    });
    let counter = 0;
    arr.forEach((num, i) => {
        if (arr[i] === arr[i+1]) {
            counter++;
        } else if (arr[i] !== arr[i + 1] && arr[i] === arr[i-1]) {
            arr[i-counter] = arr.slice(i-counter, i + 1);
            counter = 0;
        }
    });
    arr.forEach((num, i) => {
        while (arr[i][0] && arr[i][0] === arr[i + 1]) {
            arr.splice(i + 1, 1);
        }
    });
    return arr;
}

const newArray = answer(array);
console.log(newArray);
```

Comment: FWIW: The output would be more consistent and easier to use later if single elements were as, eg. `[4]`.

Comment: As far as making it simpler, consider creating a *new* array and avoiding the slicing/splicing (this, when used with a copy-before-sort, will also avoid the subtle **potential bug** that assumes newArray and array are different objects; they are not). There is also only one outer loop (and a simple inner loop) needed after the sorting.

Comment: You already have some good answers (kudos to those answerers for seeing through the code), but for future reference, remember to explain what the code is supposed to do. The answers you have would be no good if your intention is to solve a problem in, say,  orbital mechanics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another option. First push each number in object's appropriate array, then convert object to resulting array as needed.

```js
let arr = [1,2,4,591,392,391,2,5,10,2,1,1,1,20,20];

const obj = {}, res = [];

for(e of arr) !obj[e] ? obj[e] = [e] : obj[e].push(e);
for(a in obj) obj[a].length === 1 ? res.push(obj[a][0]) : res.push(obj[a]);

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make it simpler just first sort and then group them.

```js
let array = [1, 2, 4, 591, 392, 391, 2, 5, 10, 2, 1, 1, 1, 20, 20],
  last = null;

const result = array
  .sort((a, b) => a - b)
  .reduce((acc, curr, index, arr) => {
    // Getting the next element in array
    const next = arr[index + 1];
    
    if (last && last === curr) acc[acc.length - 1].push(curr);
    else if (next && next === curr) acc.push([curr]);
    else acc.push(curr);
     
    // Changing the last to the curr
    last = curr;
    
    return acc;
  }, []);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Approach that uses a Map to group the elements then sorts the Map entries by key so as not to mutate original array at all

```js
let array = [1,2,4,591,392,391,2,5,10,2,1,1,1,20,20];

const answer = (arr) =>{
   const m = new Map();
   arr.forEach(n => m.set(n, (m.get(n) || []).concat(n)));   
   return [...m.entries()].sort(([a],[b])=> a-b)
                          .map(([k,v]) => v.length > 1 ? v : v[0])
}

console.log(answer(array))
```